# Why can't Internet Explorer render this page correctly?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've been pulling my hair out but can't figure out why my page looks like a huge mess in IE9, but Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari works great.

My website is here:
http://173.244.195.179/test-o.html

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing that isn't compatible with IE9?

Comment: @Dan Grossman: Dont see why this question should not be here!

Comment: I have seen that question a million times.

Comment: Exactly. And it has been answered a million times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your source code, you have a couple of serious issues:

```
<script language=javascript type='text/javascript'> 
...
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

You have a script tag at the very top of your page. They should go inside the `head` tags. Which leads me to the next issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body><head>
...
</head>
<body>
```

You have two `<head>` tags, and two opening `<body>` tags. This should be replaced with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Oddily enough, putting the script tags inside head made it only work in IE. But putting them above doc type made it work for both browsers

Answer (score 0):

You need a Doctype. Just put

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

At the top in your HTML code.

Comment: wrong doctype type this <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Also your link and meta tags are in the body element. Place them in them in the head element.